# NSAppleScript from launchd

Tags: cocoa, applescript, launchd

I have a launchd service and a Cocoa app. The app runs when the user clicks on it from the application folder. I want to execute the following Apple Script from the service. But even though appears to work in the debug version in xcode, it does not work when it is built and installed as launchd service.

```
NSString* path = @"/Applications/Sample.app/Contents/Resources/reset.scpt";
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSAppleScript* appleScript = 
    [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
[appleScript release];
```

Comment: does Console give any hints as to what might have gone wrong when launchd attempts to run it?

Comment: Whenever you have a problem with a method that can return an error, your first step should be to (1) receive the error instead of refusing it (you are currently passing `nil` to `executeAndReturnError:`) and (2) log it. After you make these changes, what errors are you getting from `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` and `executeAndReturnError:`?

Comment: Can you post your `.plist` file which you are using for launchd?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is a problem with your launchd `.plist` file.

A common mistake with launchd is: *launchd is not shell*.
When trying to execute the apple script with launchd try to pass it to shell:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>YOUR.LABEL</string>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/zsh</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>path/to/your/apple/script</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Place the `.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/YOUR.LABEL.plist` (The filename has to correspond with the `Label` value)

Then load the plist file:

```bash
launchctl enable gui/"$(id -u)"/YOUR.LABEL
```

MacOS caches the plist file. So if you already have a plist file for your agent: Logout and login again to refresh the cache.

Now start the agent:

```bash
launchctl kickstart gui/"$(id -u)"/YOUR.LABEL
```

See: https://launchd.info/ for more info.